# Do criminals get the bounty for turning themselves in?

Tags: criminal-law

In theory the bounty money is spent to get that fugitive delivered, so could it get paid to the fugitive themself?

Comment: Which jurisdiction are you asking about. I believe only the u.s and Philippines have laws permitting bounty hunting.

Comment: Depends on the type of bounty: headhunters are paid bounties for finding employees...

Comment: Do criminals turn themselves in to get the bounty?

Comment: @Greendrake Well, if you are on the run and assume they are going to catch you anyway, then you can at least make a bit of money in the process.

Answer (score 2):

**Do criminals get the bounty for turning themselves in?**

In **[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)**, the independent charity [*Crimestoppers*](https://crimestoppers-uk.org/) can give [cash rewards](https://crimestoppers-uk.org/give-information/rewards-for-information) for information leading to an arrest and charge.

The giver of this information is [guaranteed total anonymity](https://crimestoppers-uk.org/give-information/our-guarantee-of-anonymity) so it is possible for a (suspected) criminal to claim their own reward - but due to the anonymity it is impossible to prove unless they reveal it themselves.